# Why didn't the Rebellion seek Yoda's help?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, rogue-one, yoda

Prior to the Battle of Scarif,

> Bail Organa informed Mon Mothma that they will need every edge they can get against the inevitable confrontation against the Death Star. Mon Mothma caught on that Bail was probably planning to seek out his "Jedi friend". She appeared not to know it to be Obi-Wan, let alone that Bail actually had two surviving Jedi friends.

So the question: In light of the magnitude of the situation, why did the Rebellion seek the aid of only Obi-Wan but not also Yoda when they need every advantage they can get to destroy the Death Star?

Arguably, a superweapon like the Death Star would be an issue grave enough to force Yoda out of exile if his aid had been sought to save the galaxy, in my personal opinion.

Comment: I don’t think Bail had any idea where Yoda was. I mean, Obi-Wan knew where Yoda was, and Bail knew where Obi-Wan was, but I don’t think Bail knew where Yoda was.

Answer (score 8):

### Bail didn’t know where to find him

Bail probably didn’t know where Yoda was. He knew that Obi-Wan was on Tatooine, because Obi-Wan had mentioned that he would watch over Luke there:

> **BAIL ORGANA**: My wife and I will take the girl. We’ve always talked of
> adopting a baby girl. She will be loved with us.
>
> **OBI-WAN**: And what of the boy?
>
> **YODA**: To Tatooine. To his family, send him.
>
> **OBI-WAN**: I will take the child and watch over him. Master Yoda, do you
> think Anakin’s twins will be able to defeat Darth Sidious?
>
> <sub>*Revenge of the Sith*</sub>

Now, Obi-Wan certainly knew where Yoda was:

> **BEN**: You will go to the Dagobah system.
>
> **LUKE**: Dagobah system?
>
> **BEN**: There you will learn from Yoda, the Jedi Master who instructed
> me.
>
> <sub>*The Empire Strikes Back*</sub>

However, I don’t believe there’s any evidence that he told Bail Yoda’s location, or that Obi-Wan even informed Bail that he knew where Yoda was hiding. So Bail could not have sent someone to contact Yoda.

Now, of course Bail might have  guessed that Obi-Wan knew where Yoda was. Indeed, it’s very possible that among the many things that Bail might have asked Obi-Wan, had they both survived, would have been how and where to find Yoda, and to seek his help in destroying the Death Star.

Comment: If what I read is true, the RotS novelisation apparently mentioned that Yoda arrived on Dagobah in an escape pod launched from Bail Organa's ship.

Comment: @thegreatjedi - The RotS novelization isn’t really canon anymore. Besides, I just looked at it, and I don’t see that.

Comment: @thegreatjedi - Now, the escape pod is [canon](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/E3-standard_starship_lifeboat) (though I don’t see it mentioned in the novelization), but I doubt it was launched from Bail’s ship, let alone near Dagobah.  Most escape pods could fly on their own, and some even had hyperdrives.

Comment: The Legends version of the page states that there's no hyperdrive engine in E3-type escape pods. But maybe it could be docked into a hyperdrive ring or a similar booster system...

Comment: @Essen - Plus, the Legends version of the page is Legends. ;) Not to mention, it says that Yoda stowed away on a freighter, not Bail’s ship.